# Transmitting locals to deeper partials

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

**What i have:**
Several references to the same `partial` but with different `locals` like

```
<%= render :partial => 'link/to/partial', :locals => {:fieldtype => 'textline', :text => object.text} %>
<%= render :partial => 'link/to/partial', :locals => {:fieldtype => 'list', :list => object.list, :header => 'HEADER'} %>
```

Now `_partial.html.erb` has the following line:

```
<%= render :partial => 'link/to/partial/'+fieldtype, :locals => locals %>
```

**What i want:**
Obviously `:locals => locals` does not work. How can i link all the locals to the next partial?

Comment: There might be a real way, but I would suggest that you save your locals in a hash like "my_locals" and then just pass that (i.e, `:locals => my_locals`). Then you can just send that single, known variable along, which could contain anything inside.

Comment: @MrDanA So this would be `<%= render :partial => 'link/to/partial', :locals => {:vars => Hash['fieldtype', 'textline', 'text', object.text]} %>` ? Or isn't it possible to create the Hash directly?

Comment: Ok got it! Seems to work fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just for clarification, you could put all the locals in a hash like this:

```
<% my_locals = {:fieldtype => 'textline', :text => object.text} %>
<%= render :partial => 'link/to/partial', :locals => {:my_locals => my_locals} %>
```

(Not that it can be confusing that `{}` are both used for declaring a hash and a block)

In your partial you would then do this:

```
<%= render :partial => 'link/to/partial/'+my_locals[:fieldtype], :locals => {:my_locals => my_locals} %>
```